# Android gridview adapter called on visibility change

Tags: listview, visibility, android-gridview

I set a VISIBLE gridView to be INVISIBLE and its adapter is called again (using a ViewHolder class), even though there is no use for that, and there is no call for notifyDataSetChanged...

I logged in getView method and all the items are called one by one.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Once I set the gridView visibility to become GONE, the adapter wasnt called no more, which made things flow faster.

Apparently a ListView / GridView adapter gets called when their visibility is set to "INVISIBLE" but not to GONE.